# How can I know if my Crucial 2.5 SSD can be powered with one usb

Tags: hard-drive, usb, ssd, enclosures

I have this Crucial MX300 275GB 2.5'' 7mm SSD that I want to use as a external drive with an enclosure.

I bought a Sabrent 2.5-Inch SATA to USB 3.0 Tool-free External Hard Drive Enclosure but when I connect the drive to the computer it's not recognised by the system although the power indicator light turns on.

I was assuming the drive could be powered with one USB but now I wonder if the drive needs more power and that's why it's not showing up.

Is there a way to know how much power my SSD needs before I try making it work with a power USB or something like that?

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Just in case it's a driver issue...

Comment: Thans @SirAdelaide, I'm using MacOS X, but I've tried in a PC with Windows 10 and in both is not recognised

Comment: http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/ct275mx300ssd1 says "Extreme Energy Efficiency technology within the Crucial MX300 reduces the amount of active power usage that's consumed by the drive. The Crucial MX300 extends your laptop's battery life by using only 0.075W of power, compared to a typical hard drive which uses 6.8W." So it is unlikely to be a power issue. More likely cables aren't plugged in right inside the hard disk enclosure.

Comment: For reference, USB 2 can provide 2.5 Watts

Comment: That make sense. In that case it's then unlikely to be a power issue. Thanks a lot for your help and the references.

Comment: For Windows, you might need to get into Disk Manager, and "activate" the drive before it can be accessible to OS. (I assume that USB is working and the device shows up in Disk Manager.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've been using the Crucial MX300 1TB drives and are able to power one drive off of the USB 3.0 port no problems.  So, the short answer is that, everything else working properly, there shouldn't be an issue with power.  There is a chance you have not installed your SSD in the enclosure properly.  We had a similar issue that was resolved by removing the SSD and putting it back in.  Apparently you don't have to be off by much to cause an issue.

One thing you didn't mention in your question is what other hardware is being driven off of your USB 3.0.  If you do then you might be trying to draw more power than your USB port can provide.